# Format on python string gives error

Tags: python, format

In python, I'm trying to create a string by format()

```
json_data_resp = '{"error":false,"code":"{0}","mac":"{1}","message":"Device configured successfully"}'.format(activation_code, macaddress)
```

When I execute this code, it gives me an error like so:

> KeyError: '"error"'

What is it that I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: `format` looks for `{}` to replace for the values. You have one big `{}` with some small `{]`s inside. Thats not valid syntax

Comment: OK, can you please correct this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `str.format` to create JSON strings in the first place.

Comment: Due to memory limitations of micropython, its recommended I use format : https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp8266/reference/constrained.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should escape literal braces by doubling them:

```
json_data_resp = '{{"error":false,"code":"{0}","mac":"{1}","message":"Device configured successfully"}}'.format(activation_code, macaddress)
```

Excerpt from [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> Format strings contain “replacement fields” surrounded by curly braces
>   `{}`. Anything that is not contained in braces is considered literal
>   text, which is copied unchanged to the output. If you need to include
>   a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling:
>   `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: Since I'm using micropython, the format is what is recommended instead of concatenation. This is exactly what I was unable to catch. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do `'%'` for string formatting:

```
json_data_resp = '{"error":false,"code":"%s","mac":"%s","message":"Device configured successfully"}'%(activation_code, macaddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is trying to insert a variable inside of the curly braces you put around the entire string. If you want to have curly braces in a formatted string, you have to use two.

```
string = "{{test_number: {0}}}".format(37)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) have fields inside curly braces. Each field has an optional number, name, or expression, and optional `:spec`, and an optional `!conversion`.

So, when you use this as a format string:

```
'{"error":false,"code":"{0}","mac":"{1}","message":"Device configured successfully"}'
```

You have a field named `"error"`, with spec `false,"code":"{0}","mac":"{1}","message":"Device configured successfully"`.

To format that field, you need a keyword parameter named `"error"`, and of course you don't have one.

---

Obviously, you didn't want that whole thing to be a field. But that means you need to escape the braces by doubling them:

```
'{{"error": false,"code":"{0}","mac":"{1}","message":"Device configured successfully"}}'
```

Or, better… why are you trying to create a JSON string by `str.format` in the first place? Why not just create a dict and serialize it?

```
json_data_resp = json.dumps({
    "error": False, "code": activation_code, "mac": macaddress,
    "message": "Device configured successfully"})
```